# How can I use JSON_EXTRACT with ROOM on Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

When I used json_extract in Query I have error

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such function:
>   json_extract (code 1)

Does room support json_extract function ?

This is my query :

```
select sum(json_extract((select distinct replace(tfo.products, '\','')), '$[0].qty_case')) as QtyCase from tfo where strftime('%m', dateCreated) = strftime('%m', 'now', '0 months') and armstrong2CustomersId = 'OPDB00140428AU' and armstrong2TfoId = '9466c9d5-7d58-4d92-96e0-010662aa0055'
```

Comment: Better question is does sqlite on android support this ... [the answer is no](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sqlite/+/master/dist/Android.bp) <= as you can see there is no flag `SQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1`

Comment: thanks you @Selvin

Comment: Do you have any solution to sum some field is key of json on SQLite @Selvin ?